# how to append a string to a database object in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi there i have following code i have different elements in feature_list = `['spa','castle','country_house','coast','golf','boutique','civil','private_hire','city','gay']`. In database there value is either 1 or 0. so i am  trying to check if they are 1 and append them into new array.

```
try:
        hotel_main = models.Hotel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except models.Hotel.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            hotel_main = models.Hotel.objects.get(id=id)
        except models.Hotel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    feature_list = ['spa','castle','country_house','coast','golf','boutique','civil','private_hire','city','gay']
    hotel_features = []
    for feature in feature_list: 
        if hotel_main.feature == 1: 
            hotel_features.append(feature)
```

Its giving me follwing error:**'Hotel' object has no attribute 'feature'**

But in my understanding feature should represent the string of the array... please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. try this -

```
hotel_main = models.Hotel.objects.get(slug=slug)
feature_list = ['spa','castle','country_house','coast','golf','boutique','civil','private_hire','city','gay']
hotel_features = []
for feature in feature_list: 
    if getattr(hotel_main, feature, 1):
        hotel_features.append(feature)
```

The reason what you are doing will give an exception is because you are dynamically checking column fields with the hotel_main object. the `.` functionality I dont think works for string literals. Hence the introduction of `getattr`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: cool, glad to help. please upvote if my (or any answer) has helped.

Answer (score 0):

> But in my understanding feature should represent the string of the array... please correct me

You are correct that the string from the array is assigned to `feature`, however your problem is in calling `hotel_main.feature`. Python thinks you are looking for an attribute named 'feature' on the hotel_main object. To look for an attribute using what is currently assigned to the variable you should use [Python's built-in getattr function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
feature_value = getattr(hotel_main, feature, 0) //default to not having the feature
if feature_value == 1:
    // the rest of your code
```